# Run multiple OpenGL shaders on a CVImageBuffer

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, fragment-shader

Relating to my previous two questions I've spent a week attempting to figure out how to run multiple shaders against a core video buffer. I *know* what I need to do but I, frankly, can't get the code to work (pasted below is the original, non ping-pong version).

Lacking the Eureka moment I'm now totally stuck :). The code to compile and link the shaders is not shown for brevity. The whole thing renders (successfully - but one shader overwrites the other - so missing the vital step) to a GL compatible layer and theres a UIToolbar underneath which, eventually, will have a button per shader and a button to run all shaders.

Thanks,

Simon

```
-(void) DrawFrame:(CVImageBufferRef)cameraframe;
{
    int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraframe);
    int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraframe);

    // Create a new texture from the camera frame data, display that using the shaders
    glGenTextures(1, &videoFrameTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoFrameTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // Using BGRA extension to pull in video frame data directly
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraframe));

    static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,
    };

    [self setDisplayFramebuffer];

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoFrameTexture);

    // Update uniform values
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_VIDEOFRAME], 0);   

    // Update attribute values.
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON);


    glUseProgram(greyscaleProgram);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    [self presentFramebuffer];

    // Obviously here is where the ping pong starts (assuming correct mods 
    // to the framebuffer setup method below
    glUseProgram(program);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    [self presentFramebuffer];

    glDeleteTextures(1, &videoFrameTexture);
}

- (void)setDisplayFramebuffer;
{
    if (context)
    {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

        if (!viewFramebuffer)
        {
            [self createFramebuffers];
        }

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);



        glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

    }
}

- (BOOL)presentFramebuffer;
{
    BOOL success = FALSE;

    if (context)
    {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

        success = [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
    }

    return success;
}

- (BOOL)createFramebuffers
{   
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Onscreen framebuffer object
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

    // Render buffer for final output
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];

    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);
    NSLog(@"Backing width: %d, height: %d", backingWidth, backingHeight);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);


    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Failure with framebuffer generation");
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Edit:** Clarified what is missing

Comment: Hello! I don't understand what the problem is, you say first that the code doesn't work, but later you say the rendering is successful, can you please specify what doesn't work?

Comment: @Matias - Hi, thanks for looking. The code above is the original code that only works with one shader. There are two shaders in the source code but one overwrites the other as there is no render to texture/ping pong method in place. I followed your advice and have been researching too but just hit a dead end. So the code above is 'back to the beginning'. It's a little lame to have to start again but I was beginning to get really lost so a restart made sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do ping-pong rendering, you need to do the following:

- Create 2 textures, with the exact same configuration
- Create 2 Framebuffers with the same configuration, and attach one texture to each framebuffer.

Let's call the Framebuffers A and B, and the attached textures texA and texB:

To render:

- Use the first shader with glUseProgram.
- Bind Framebuffer A.
- Render a quad.

Now you have the result of the shader execution in texA. To do the ping-pong:

- Use the second shader with glUseProgram.
- Bind Framebuffer B.
- Bind texA and setup texture units for your shader.
- Render a quad.
- Use shader with glUseProgram.
- Bind Framebuffer A.
- Bind texB and setup texture units.
- Render a quad.

Now you have the result in texA and you can repeat the process again, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That's the clearest I've seen it put. Will be coding this tomorrow evening so I'll put my code up here. I'd be grateful if you'd take a peek then. Happy to up the bounty more if need be :)

Comment: I've got this working with two shaders now. Should it fail to work when I set up a look (as hinted at in your description) I'll post another bounty.  Thanks again.

Comment: why do i need 2 frame buffers? can't i use 1 frame buffer and attach 2 textures to it?